# Eden, Adam and Eve as Midrash

Tags: genesis, judaism, resource-request

Can anyone point me to any detailed articles, books or theses that expound Genesis 2-3 as midrash; ie; the idea that the Eden-Fall story is a midrashic tale to explain creation and fall?

Comment: A Midrash of what - Midrash has no meaning unless the source is defined.

Comment: Search for genesis as allegory or allegorical, also Genesis as mytho-historical genre.

Answer (score 1):

**For Midrash (מדרשׁ) about Chavah (חַוָּ֑ה) & Ha-Adam (הָֽאָדָ֛ם) from  Bereishit (בראשית) Chapters 2-3**, perhaps research commentaries by Rashi & other scholars @ [https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.20?with=Rashi&lang=bi&aliyot=0].

**Rashi - Commentary on Bereishit 3:20** :

> חוה EVE — חוה has the same sound as חיה (and similar meaning “life”) — she was so called because she gives life (birth) to her children; the interchange of ‘י and ‘ו is similar to that in (Ecclesiastes 2:22), מה הוה לאדם “for what hath a man”, where הוה is used in the sense of היה “to be.”